# How can I tell if a Java Date and time zone is before the current time?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

My class has 2 properties that make up its date:

```
java.util.Date date;
String timeZone;
```

How can I see if this date is before the current time on the server?

Basically I want to write something like this, but take timeZone into account:

```
return date.before(new Date());
```

Comment: `Date` stores internally as UTC, so your `timeZone` variable is not necessary and confusing.

Comment: The `timeZone` is the time zone of the user that created the date.

Comment: How are you constructing your `Date`?

Comment: Its sent from an html form and then saved in the DB.

Comment: This question was answered previously:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911924/struggling-with-how-to-compare-hours-with-different-time-zones-in-java

Comment: That doesn't really answer this question.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startTimeZoneOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(startDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
    startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
    startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, startTimeZoneOffset);

    Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int nowTimeZoneOffset = nowCalendar.getTimeZone().getOffset(new Date().getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
    nowCalendar.setTime(new Date());
    nowCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, nowTimeZoneOffset);

    return startCalendar.before(nowCalendar);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Date` stores internally as UTC, so your `timeZone` variable is not necessary. You can simply use `Date.before(Date)`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class, which is always in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) becomes a non-issue.

```
someInstant.isBefore( Instant.now() )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

As the [correct Answer by Kuo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720048/642706) stated, your `java.util.Date` is recording a moment in UTC. So no need for a time zone.

Likewise, its replacement, the `java.time.Instant` class, also records a moment in UTC. So no time zone needed.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current in UTC.
```

So all you need as member variables on your class is `Instant`.

```
public class Event {
    Instant when ;
    …
}
```

To compare `Instant` objects, use the `isAfter`, `isBefore`, and `equals` methods.

```
someInstant.isBefore( Instant.now() )
```

For presentation in a time zone expected by the user, assign a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. The `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` both represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but viewed through different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;     // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
String output = zdt.toString() ;              // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.
```

Or let *java.time* automatically localize output. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).